# MPMediaPlayback currentPlaybackTime in minutes

Tags: iphone, ios, mpmovieplayercontroller

How can I display the `currentPlaybackTime` property of `MPMediaPLayback` in minutes rather seconds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Display this string:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d:%02d", (seconds / 60), (seconds % 60))];
```

Isn't that all there is to it?

Answer (score 2):

Presumably, you could just divide it by 60?

Comment: Well, I'd like to display the time in this format: `2:15` (min/sec)